# Can I select fetch the primary key of a table through another element that is not unique?

Tags: vb.net

I have a combo box where the user selects a Username that is in a table, I want to know if there is any way I can fetch that table's primary key through that Username.

I tried it, but it just can't seem to get the data, I don't think that it's going to work since a username is not unique.

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE User = John
```

I just want a way to get the primary key through the username.

Comment: What do you mean by the username is not unique ? Does that mean you have the same username multiple times with different primary keys?

Comment: When you load the rows from your database, set the PrimaryKey as the `ValueMember` of the ComboBox and the `UserName` as the `DisplayMember`. Get the `SeletedValue`, containing the DB PKey when a selection is made.

Comment: @Jimi Your skill in deduction have increased by 10 point.

Comment: how your table schema... to get a primarykey you need a autoincrement column and then SELECT id, * FROM Users WHERE User = John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you actually are trying to get a PK from a Query you can do this with ExecuteScalar method. The reason you query is not working is because you need to enclose the search string in single quotes. 'johnny' or user parameters, which is the preferred method. Below is an example that assumes the PK is of type integer.

Jimi raises a good point, if you already have the data in a datatable you can simply just use the pkcolumn as a ValueMember on the combobox and not make another trip to the DB

```
Private Function GetPK(ByVal Uid As String) As Integer
    Using SqlConn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Your connection string")
        Using Cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 PKColumn FROM TABLENAME WHERE UsernameColumn =@UserName")
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Uid
            Dim PkObj As Object = Cmd.ExecuteScalar
            If PkObj IsNot Nothing Then
                Return CType(PkObj, Integer)
            Else
                'user not found
                Return Nothing
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```